# Does carry weight affect stealth?

Tags: fallout-4

I know armour weight affects stealth, but does how much you're carrying have any effect? (More text so that it meets quality standards)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does armor affect stealth?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243532/how-does-armor-affect-stealth)

Comment: This one is definitely not armor related

Comment: The answer does not limit itself to armor weight, so, it could potentially be changed to ask about how weight effect stealth.

Comment: If it would have to be changed to make it a duplicate, that means it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Encumbrance does not seem to affect stealth on the difficulty levels I most frequently play, but I only have gameplay experience on this, not a source.

Comment: I'd definitely say not a duplicate, as it's carry weight vs. worn armor weight. It's actually a good question that I'm curious on, as well, being a major hoarder. I hope whoever answers it also addresses how stealth is affected if you are over-encumbered... You'd expect the slowdown penalty to perhaps help your stealth, moving slower and all... but I felt like it was the same, maybe worse, as being under the weight limit. It'd be good to learn some facts behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Carry weight does not have any effects on stealth.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could document this.

Comment: It's correct to some degree at least - absolute weight certainly doesn't influence it, my character with cheated carry weight has half of wasteland in eq and isn't penalized for that.