# Is shadowed armor better than no armor for sneaking?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, it is believed that your ability to sneak is [dependent on your armor weight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243532/how-does-armor-affect-stealth) (with heavier armor being worse). However, armor pieces can be modified with the *shadowed* modification, which *"Improves stealth in dark areas..."*.

Does this outweigh the negative effect of the armor weight?

Even if it does outweigh the armor weight and yields a net detectability decrease, this (supposedly) only works in dark areas. So then you would actually be better off wearing no armor at all when sneaking in well or medium-lit areas (no armor weight).

I guess it really boils down to which of the following is better for pure stealth:

- Shadowed armor with lightweight modification
- No armor

*(The armor does of course offer some protection, but let's set that aside for now)*

Answer (score 2):

My solution, mod for Shadowed AND Muffled. This will pretty much negate any negative effects your armor's weight has, as long as it's not like, insanely heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Well think of it like this, there is about four types of armor
leather which is the lightweight type 
radier is a bit heavy but offers a better protection
combat armor has even greater protection form lasers and bullets but is heavy
metal armor is close to bulletproof but is super heavy
If you have stealth in mind, stick to leather. You can add lightweight and shadowed to the armor and look like a ninja as well. With this armor you are near impossible to see or hear even in some dudes line of sight

Answer (score -3):

Your armor weight only affects your ability to sneak if you move if no enemy has a clear LoS on you. If you are in a well-lit area and move while an enemy could see you, he'll detect you, no matter if you wear shadowed or no armor.

Since shadowed armor already has a extremely low weight (especially when modded lightweight), it barely affects your sneak ability negatively compared to no armor, but gives you a huge bonus when in a darker area. So yes, the shadowed armor is better than no armor.

Comment: You can definitely hide from people in daylight when they have clear line of sight. Do you have any evidence for the first sentence or the size of the shadowed bonus ("huge")?

Comment: @DCShannon My evidence are my own 90 hours of Fallout 4 in which i mostly sneak (yes, some stuff has to be found out first) and a few lets plays I watch. I've never managed it to hide in a well-lit area from enemies which had a decent perception. Of course, you can hide from ghouls or rad-roaches, but if you face higher-leveled supermutants, androids or raiders, good luck hiding there. As for the shadowed bonus, the description says that you are harder to detect, and since I wear it, I can move a lot closer to enemies without being detected.

Comment: One way I could see this working is that armor weight may affect the _sound_ part of detection, while the shadowed modification affects the _visual_ part. So it could be that adding shadowed armor increases the noise you make when moving (due to weight), but reduces their chance to visually spot you (in dark areas).

Comment: @Svj0hn Well, i thought that was obvious. The shadowed modification reduces the visual part. The sound part is only affected by the lightweight modification since the heavier your armor is, the more noise it makes.

Comment: @YUNOWORK In that case your first statement says that sound makes no difference when in line of sight. So again, when sneaking in daylight (or just out of sight), no armor would be better than shadowed armor.